# How do I check when a model's method runs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am kind of new in Ruby (Less than 6 months of experience) and I am trying to check when a method inside a `model.rb` file runs. I thought it would always run every time I instantiated a new model but, apparently, not. At least it is not running.

I have even put some `binding.pry` to stop running but it did not stop creating the model, meaning that method `trails_available` was not called, right ?

```rb
 def trails_available= value
    binding.pry
    self.db_trails_available = value
  end

  def trails_available
    binding.pry
    if self.db_trails_available
      unless self.db_trails_available.empty?
        self.db_trails_available
      else
        trails_available = Trail.available(0,self.id).pluck(:id)
        self.update_attribute(:db_trails_available, trails_available)
        trails_available
      end
    end
  end
```

The model's file name is `company_profile.rb` and when I instantiated a new company profile the variable `db_trails_available` returned a blank array "[ ]". see below:

```rb
<CompanyProfile:0x0000001161e908
 id: 232,
 company_id: 13,
 access_type: "test_7",
 blocked_trails_ids: [nil, 68],
 deleted_at: nil,
 created_at: Wed, 25 Sep 2019 12:40:42 -03 -03:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 25 Sep 2019 12:40:42 -03 -03:00,
 blocked_components_ids: [nil, 170],
 blocked_materials_ids: [nil, 723],
 school_id: 13,
 available_minutes: nil,
 blocked_academies_ids: [nil, 1],
 db_trails_available: [],
 db_components_available: [],
 db_materials_available: [],
 top_components: [],
 optional_materials_ids: [nil, 723],
 optional_components_ids: [nil, 170],
 optional_trails_ids: [nil, 68],
 skip: true>
```

What am I doing wrong to chek out when `trails_available` runs ?

Comment: _I thought it would always run every time I instantiated a new model_. No, it doesn't. Can you explain further what you're trying to do? Maybe there is more than one explanation for that.

Comment: Shure ! I need to understand how ":db_trails_available" is created and than how to sort it manually. Thanks.

Comment: I have already tried to find where "trails_available" is called, using CTRL + SHIFT + F, but failed.

Comment: It seems I got your point. Remove everything you have on `trails_available`, try with `def trails_available
  return self[:db_trails_available] if self[:db_trails_available].present?
  
  Trail.available(0, id).ids
end`.